# Getting tasks Assigned To the groups

Tags: 2010, groups, task-list

I have one sharepoint group with contribute permission which has 3 users. If any one of the group member is logged in to the sharepoint site, he will get the tasks that are assigned to that **group** and assigned to that **logged in user**. please help me to achieve this goal. All the suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve your goal is by dropping the task web part on the page and use SharePoint designer to change the query part of the list view. Here's the query that will show the user's task and the group's task.

```
   <Query>
    <Where>
      <And>
        <Or>
          <Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups">
            <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/>
          </Membership>
          <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/>
            <Value Type="Integer">
              <UserID Type="Integer"/>
            </Value>
          </Eq>
        </Or>
        <Neq>
          <FieldRef Name="Status" />
          <Value Type="Text">Completed</Value>
        </Neq>
      </And>
    </Where>
    <OrderBy>
      <FieldRef Name="Created" Ascending="FALSE"/>
      <FieldRef Name="ID" Ascending="FALSE"/>
    </OrderBy>
  </Query>
```